# How to get value from joining row and column in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data like this and I call it table normal:

```
 Z      0        0.01       0.02  
---  ------     -------    ------

-3.4  0.0003    0.0003     0.0003

-3.3  0.0005    0.0005     0.0005

-3.2  0.0007    0.0007     0.0006

-3.1  0.001     0.0009     0.0009

-3    0.0013    0.0013     0.0013
```

And I have value of `Z = -3.21`

it means value of Z in `rows = -3.2` and in `column = 0.01`

So, I will get the value = `0.0007`

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: @kevin - thanks for editing it, because I already use {} to make it neat, but it wouldn't let me

Comment: `{}` is just the icon for `code`, i guess. So, either indent the individual lines with `4 spaces` or select the code snippet and click on `{}` :)

Comment: i have understood just `Please help` . can you explain what you want and wished result ?

Comment: @samir - i wish the result is got from column and row. for example: the row is -3.2 and the column is 0.01 (Please look at the table above)

Answer (score 0):

You run the following query through mysql and the value of `value` is the number you want

```
<?php
    $value = -3.21;

    $Z = number_format($value * 10, 0, '', '') / 10;

    $col = substr(floor($value * 100), -1);
    if ($col > 0) { 
        $col /= 100; 
    }

    $query = "SELECT `$col` as `value` FROM `normal` WHERE Z = '$Z'";
    // $query = "SELECT `0.01` as `value` FROM `normal` WHERE Z = '-3.2'";
```